# Sigma notation with conditions

Tags: summation, notation

I would like to express an average of values of set S out of H when all the values from set S are greater than zero.
Is the following expression clear? Is it possible to express this better?

$$
F(H) = \frac{\sum_{i \in S}^{} {e_{i}[S \subseteq H \land (e_{i} > 0 ,\forall i \in S )]}}{|S|} 
$$

Comment: The best way to express this is using words.  "Let  $f(H)$ be the average value of the positive elements of $H$." Why make your reader parse some complicated notation when ordinary English works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want $ \forall i \in S $ in there, because you already introduced $ i $ in the summation.  I'm also not sure what $ S $ is supposed to be doing; is it an additional parameter that affects the value of $ F ( H ) $? (in which case you probably should make this explicit, as $ F ( H , S ) $ or even $ F ( S ) $ since it's $ S $ that matters most); or is it always the set of *all* positive elements of $ H $? (as @Ethan Bolker's comment assumes).

I'll assume that it's always the set of all elements $ i $ of $ H $ indexing a positive value $ e _ i $.  So for the sum over all elements of $ S $, I'd write something like $$ \sum _ { \scriptstyle i \in H \atop \scriptstyle e _ i > 0 } e _ i \text .$$  Another approach is $$ \sum _ { i \in H } \max ( e _ i , 0 ) $$ (and there are some notations that people have for $ \max ( x , 0 ) $, like $ x ^ + $, if that comes up a lot).  For the denominator, you can write $$ \sum _ { \scriptstyle i \in H \atop \scriptstyle e _ i > 0 } 1 $$ or $$ \lvert \{ i \in H \; | \; e _ i > 0 \} \rvert \text . $$  You could write the whole thing as $$ \mathop { \operatorname { avg } } \limits _ { \scriptstyle i \in H \atop \scriptstyle e _ i > 0 } e _ i \text , $$ where you'd have to define the symbol $ \mathop { \operatorname { avg } } $ as an operator behaving like $ \sum $ but taking an average instead of a sum; this might be a handy symbol to have if you're going to be taking lots of averages.  Finally, you could write it as $$ \frac { \displaystyle \sum _ { i \in S } e _ i } { \lvert S \rvert } $$ and then put ‘where $ S : = \{ i \in H \; | \; e _ i > 0 \} $’ off to the side.